# Extract 100 sections from a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector of length 1000. It contains (numeric) survey answers of 100 participants, thus 10 answers per participant. I would like to drop the first three values for every participant to create a new vector of length 700 (including only the answers to questions 4-10).

I only know how to extract every n-th value of the vector, but cannot figure how to solve the above problem.

```
vector <- seq(1,1000,1)
```

Expected output:

```
4 5 6 7 8 9 10    14 15 16 17 18 19 20    24 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing example data, based on which this thread is reproducible. Here is one solution

```
c(matrix(vector, 10)[4:10, ])
```

We first convert the vector to a matrix with 10 rows, so that each column attributes to a participant. Then use row subsetting to remove first three rows. Finally the matrix is flattened to a vector again.

Answer (score 2):

Using a matrix to first structure and then flatten is one method. Another somewhat similar method is to use what I am calling a "logical pattern index":

```
head(             # just showing the first couple of "segments"
  vector[ c( rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 10-3) ) ], 
    15)
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 24
```

This method can also be use inside the two argument version of `[` to select rows ore columns using a logical pattern index. This works because of R's recycling of logical indices.

Comment: Thank you also for this answer. Sorry that I cannot approve both answers.